# Verilog Concatenation Problem

Tags: digital-logic, verilog

When I try making the concatenation mapping below, I get the following outputs. Is there anything in particular that's wrong with my mapping ideas?

[image][image]

Comment: In the assignment it says you are first supposed to concatenate them together before you split them up again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there anything in particular that's wrong with my mapping ideas?

That fact that the 'mismatch' signal goes high says there is.

What is wrong is that you are mixing up LS and MS bits when you split up your values. W needs the whole of A and the **MS** bits of B. You are assigning the LS bits!

There is a simple solution splitting a nasty vector like that without having to worry where all the boundaries are:

assign {W,X,Y,Z} = {a,b,c,d,e,f,2'b11};

Comment: So a[4:2] would be MSB's?

Comment: Yes. As A has index [4:0] the value [4:2] are the three MS bits.